# Weblogic not coming up inside the Dockder container

Tags: docker, weblogic, weblogic12c

Weblogic is not coming up . It is giving following stack trace . Can any one help in solving that ?

```
<Jun 20, 2018 1:04:27,029 PM UTC> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.rjvm.RJVMService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.protocol.ProtocolRegistrationService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.protocol.ProtocolRegistrationService
A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.rjvm.RJVMService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.protocol.ProtocolRegistrationService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.protocol.ProtocolRegistrationService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at weblogic.utils.net.AddressUtils.getIPForLocalHost(AddressUtils.java:163)
    at weblogic.rjvm.JVMID.setLocalID(JVMID.java:278)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMService.setJVMID(RJVMService.java:72)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMService.start(RJVMService.java:54)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.utils.net.AddressUtils$AddressMaker.getAllAddresses(AddressUtils.java:62)
    at weblogic.utils.net.AddressUtils$AddressMaker.<clinit>(AddressUtils.java:45)
    at weblogic.utils.net.AddressUtils.getIPForLocalHost(AddressUtils.java:163)
    at weblogic.rjvm.JVMID.setLocalID(JVMID.java:278)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMService.setJVMID(RJVMService.java:72)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

---

The WebLogic Server encountered a critical failure
Reason: Assertion violated

---

Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.

Comment: Based on [a blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/luzmestre/javalangassertionerror%3a-could-not-obtain-the-localhost-address-in-a-new-12c-install) it seems we'll need to see the full log to know what name it was trying to look up when it failed.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLDaniel , Problem got resolved , Actually there was an interface resolution problem inside the docker container which was causing this .

Comment: @DHRUV you should enter your solution as an answer and accept it in order to help others in the future

Comment: Sure @kbrian187

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was an interface resolution problem inside the docker container which was causing this

Make sure following points for resolution : 
1) Cat /etc/hosts should have entry corresponding to localhost 
2) docker0 interface should be in up state